# Typed DataSet merge issue

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

This is about C# typed dataSets

I have a typed dataset, I have used a partial class of the Row of the datatable and have added a new public int to it.

I can set that int, but when i call the Merge() to merge a bunch of data together the added public int is lost (goes back to 0).

Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have added the new int-property to the Cs-sourcecode only.

if you edit the xsd-file that belongs to the dataset with visualstudio and add the int-field there (into the xsd) your dataset sould be regenerated and contain the new int-field as property.
Merge(), GetXml() .. should work as expected. The new value is not automatically persisted into the database.

Comment: Yes i only added the property to c# source. but i did it in a partial class that i added, I did not modify the generated class. Youve given me an idea though. Do i need to override the base implementation of Merge?? i.e. do base.merge and also update my new property myself?

Comment: I thing you dont need to override the base implementation of Merge, since every required code is infered from the underlying xsd